# Node.js and RabbitMQ - best way to init connection on server start

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Trying to implement `RabbitMQ` on my already existing codebase written on `koa.js`, faced the problem that I actually don't know what is the best way to do that. Most tutorials I faced in the web left me with idea establishing connection to RabbitMQ server each time I want to send or receive the message. That makes sense when I am receiving message in worker, but how to establish connection on provider side?

I read that that is a bad thing to establish connection each time when I create channel or send message. So the idea is that I need to create connection when I am starting server, so atm I do it like this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, async () => {
  await rabbit.createConnection(`amqp://localhost:5672`);
  global.rabbit = rabbit;

  console.log(
    `\n Server listening on port: ${PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode \n`
  );
});
```

Is this a good spot or not? 
Thanks for your advices!

P.S. In my rabbit instance I save the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the RabbitMQ connection once and *keep the connection alive*. Only reconnect if the connection should die for some reason. Whether you do this in your index.js or when you start Koa depends on your app, but in general it doesn't really matter as long as you are able to connect and shutdown properly.

Making a new connection for each publish or consume is insane from a performance perspective.

To simplify reconnections, try a [amqp connection manager](https://github.com/benbria/node-amqp-connection-manager). It handles reconnects transparently.

Comment: Thanks, that was the same thing I was thinking about

Comment: But, what to do if the message is sent at the moment of reconnection?